# PHP Dynamic text file creation

Tags: php, file, chmod

I have this code

```
$ext = ".txt";
$filename = $namef.$ext;
if(!file_exists($filename))
{
$file = fopen($filename,"w");
fwrite($file, $privatekey);
fclose($file);
chmod($file,0777);
}
```

`$namef` is any name that gets input into this program.
However when I run this, I keep getting:

```
Unable to access (name_of_file).txt in something.php
Warning: fopen(name_of_file.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file      or directory in something.php 
Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in ./something.php on line 79

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in ./something.php on line 80

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Unable to access in ./something.php on line 81
```

May i know if dynamic text file name creation is possible?

Thank you

Comment: Have you set the cdmod to 777 in the writing folder?

Comment: please check the paths or at least give real data of your codes and structure to help others help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this simple code no need of if statements. it will open the file in read write mode and create automatically if it doesn,t exist or open a file if it already exists.

> `$ext = ".txt";
>
>   $filename = $namef.$ext;
>
>   $file = fopen($filename,"w+");
>
>   fwrite($file, $privatekey);
>
>   fclose($file);
>
>   chmod($file,0777);`

Comment: He may want to create the file only if it doesnt exist

Comment: ok than try this if (file_exists('http://www.mydomain.com/directory/'.$filename)) {
 … }

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question. Yes it is possible to create file with "dynamic" file name.

For creating file you can use [file_put_contents();](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.
>
> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

If you want to append text to file with already exists use **FILE_APPEND** flag

> **FILE_APPEND**    If file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.

**Example:**

```
 $ext = ".txt";
 $filename = $namef.$ext;
 file_put_contents($filename, $privatekey, FILE_APPEND);
```

If you want file to be created if doesn't exists or to be overwritten don't use **FILE_APPEND** flag

**Example:**

```
 $ext = ".txt";
 $filename = $namef.$ext;
 file_put_contents($filename, $privatekey);
```

Also make sure you have proper rights in directory where you want to do file operations.